# How to find all occurrences of a substring (with wildcards allowed) in a given String

Tags: java, regex, string, search, wildcard

I'm searching for an efficient way for a wildcard-enabled search in Java. My first approach was of course to use regex. However this approach does NOT find ALL possible matches!

Here's the code:

```
    public static ArrayList<StringOccurrence> matchesWildcard(String string, String pattern, boolean printToConsole) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(normalizeWildcards(pattern));
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    ArrayList<StringOccurrence> res = new ArrayList<StringOccurrence>();
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()){
        res.add(new StringOccurrence(m.start(), m.end(), count, m.group()));
        if(printToConsole)
            System.out.println(count + ") " + m.group() + ", " + m.start() + ", " + m.end());
        count +=1;
    }
    return res;
```

For a query q: ab*b and a String str: abbccabbccbbb I get the output:
0) abb, 0, 3
1) abb, 5, 8
But the whole String should be also a result, because it matches the pattern. It seems that the Java-implementation of regex starts each new search after the last match...

Any ideas how this could work (or suggestions for frameworks...)?

Comment: The entire string abbccabbccbbb does *not* match ab*b.

Comment: Can you print output of `normalizeWildcards(pattern)` call?

Comment: And even `abbccab` OR `abbccabb` are matches too for `ab.*?b`

Comment: normalizeWildcards() changes ab*b to ab.*?b

Answer (score 0):

`ab*b` means "a" followed by zero or more "b" followed by a "b". The minimum match would be "ab". Soulds like you're looking for something like: `a[a-z]*b` where `[a-z]*` indicates zero or more of any lowercase letter. You may also want to bound it so that the start of the "word" must be an "a" and the end must be a "b": `\ba[a-z]*b\b`

Comment: No wait, now the two included `abb` are not found. How can I also include the possibility that no character is in between?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. I assume you mean "a" followed by anything (or nothing) followed by an ending "b".

Comment: In my implementation, if I search in `wabbccabbccbbb` with the regex query `ab[a-z]*b` then I get only one result: `0) abbccab, 1, 8`. However I want to get all possibilities that are contained. Maybe it is the Java-implementation...

Comment: @user2833829 Why don't you realize that what you want to find in a string cannot be found with regular expressions? It's not a Java problem, no other regex engine can do it.

Comment: @laune Maybe you are right, but I still don't believe it. `matchesWildcard("wabbccabbccbbb", "a[a-z]b{0,}", true);` has the result: `0) abb, 1, 4
1) abb, 6, 9` but it should return all the other possibilities. If you know why it doesn't, please tell me.

Comment: @user2833829 Because that's the way regular expressions work. See my additions to my answer. (I know regex in grep, awk, sed, Perl, Java, XSLT.)

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `*` to mean `.*` and `.*?` at the same time (and more).

You should reconsider what you really need. Let's extend your example:

abbccabbccbbbcabb

Do you really want all possibilities?

To achieve what you want you'll have to

```
iterate p1 over all occurrences of "ab"
    from p1+2 on
    iterate p2 over all occurrences of "b"
        output substring between p1 and p2+1
```

This is the corresponding Java code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    String s = "abbccabbccbbb";
    int f1 = 0;
    int p1;
    while( (p1 = s.indexOf( "ab", f1 )) >= 0 ){
        int f2 = p1 + 2;
        int p2;
        while( (p2 = s.indexOf( "b", f2 )) >= 0 ){
            System.out.println( s.substring( p1, p2 + 1 ) );
            f2 = p2 + 1;
        }
        f1 = p1 + 2;
    }
}
```

Below is the output. You may be surprised - maybe that's more than you expect, but then you'll need to refine your specification.

```
abb 0:3
abbccab 0:7
abbccabb 0:8
abbccabbccb 0:11
abbccabbccbb 0:12
abbccabbccbbb 0:13
abb 5:8
abbccb 5:11
abbccbb 5:12
abbccbbb 5:13
```

**Later**

Why is a single regular expression not capable of doing it?

The basic mechanism of pattern matching is to try and match the regex against a string, starting at some position, initially 0. If a match is found, **this position is advanced according to the matched string**. The pattern matcher never looks back.

A pattern ab.*?b will try and find the next 'b' after an "ab". This means that *no match is possible beginning with the same "ab" and ending at some 'b' following that previously found "next 'b'".

In other words: one regex cannot find overlapping substrings.

Comment: Yes I need all possibilities! BTW: normalizeWildcards() changes ab*b to ab.*?b for me. So what you are saying is I should match both  .* and .*?

Comment: See the pseudo-code I added. You can't do that with a single regex patztern match.

Comment: Yes, that would work for this case. But there may be other cases that are even more complex. That's why I wanted to use regex. For example a query could be `ab[a-z]*b*a*b?b`...

Comment: Why didn't you say so in the first place? Trying to make do with a false start and asking others to fix it for the trivial case isn't a good style to ask a question - it's no style at all. - It's still possible to find all overlapping matches for a pattern as given in the preceding comment using my approach, but you'll have to use a more sophisticated technique for the nested iterations - obviously a set of nested while loops isn't possible in this case.

Comment: Yes, that's correct (_"one regex cannot find overlapping substrings"_). And that's the reason why it is not working like I expected. But somehow this is wrong/not intuitive. If you look at the finite state automaton that models regex, this should be possible. But it doesn`t seem to be implemented like that, obviously to increase performance. Anyway, thanks for your solution.

Comment: Sorry, but the title is "How to find all occurrences of a substring (**with wildcards allowed**) in a given String" which means '*' and '?' may occur multiple times, at arbitrary positions in the query String.

Comment: There are three different wildcards, which alone would advocate the plural. It only goes to show that verbal specs are misleading, as is the simplest possible example.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need all possible matches, this answer is not useful for you (anyway maybe other user finds it useful).

If the widest match would be sufficient for you, then use a greedy quantifier (I guess you're using a reluctant one, showing your pattern would be useful).

Google for greedy vs reluctant quantifiers for regex.

Cheers.